# How can I create a solidity function that passes a storage pointer instead of creating a copy?

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

The following contract fails (I believe) because when `Wordbase.set` is called, it creates a new `Node` in storage, rather than passing the old `Node`. Thus, the value updates on the copy instead of the original.

How can I get a contract to pass a pointer instead of creating a copy?

```
contract Wordbase {

  struct Node {
    bytes32 value;
    mapping(bytes32 => Node) nodes;
  }

  mapping(address => Node) realms;

  function getNode(address addr , bytes32[] fields) internal returns (Node) {
    Node node = realms[addr];
    for (uint i = 0; i < fields.length; i ++) {
      node = node.nodes[fields[i]];
    }
    return node;
  }

  function get(address addr, bytes32[] fields) constant returns (bytes32) {
    return getNode(addr, fields).value;
  }

  function get(bytes32[] fields) constant returns (bytes32) {
    return get(msg.sender, fields);
  }

  function set(bytes32[] fields, bytes32 value) {
    getNode(msg.sender, fields).value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#in-memory-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the return type of `getNode` to `storage`.

i.e.

```
function getNode(address addr , bytes32[] fields) internal returns (Node storage) {
    Node node = realms[addr];
    for (uint i = 0; i < fields.length; i ++) {
      node = node.nodes[fields[i]];
    }
    return node;
}
```